# grant permission in linux

Tags: linux, permissions, chmod

I have a linux web server with 2 hard-drives.
There are 2 users, one can access /home/user1 and the other user can access /home2/user2

I would like to grant user1 permissions to access /home2/users/ (recursively) without revoking user2 access to his home directory.

What's the best way to do that?

Comment: Put both into the same group or use ACLs. In any case, this is off-topic here, promoted to move to serverfault :)

Answer (score 1):

put both of them in the same group, and change the permission for the following:

```
RWX------ /home1/user1
RWXRWX--- /home2/user2
```

Thanks to @Niklas B: you'll also need to set /home2/user2 dir SGID to the group they both members.

if it's the main user2's group it'll be automatic, if not- use 'chgrp' command (don't forget -r for recursive! =))

Comment: Why change the permissions of /home1/user1? This is not necessary (at least not if you create a new group for the purpose)

Comment: No really needed, this is just the usual permission for home folders

Comment: Still, you'd need the SGID bit on `/home/user2` to make the permissions propagate.

Comment: Yes, absolutely- you're right.

Comment: Please add that to the answer! You can edit on SO

Answer (score 0):

Create a group (users) for both users and grant the group r/w/x access to the second home dir ;)

Comment: Ahh, Niklas beat me by seconds :P

Comment: This is not a universal solution. At least you'd need SGID in addition to propagate this to new files and directories.

Answer (score 0):

If users are in same group, then you can set group permissions to folder users.
Or if you not want other users access to /home2/users you can create new group and add user1 and user2 to it. After set permission on new group.

Answer (score 0):

Have the `user1` be in a group, say, `group1` and allow `group1` to access `/home2/users`.

Assuming you have setup user1 be in a group called "group1"

`chgrp -R  group1 /home2/users`

`chmod -R 770 /home2/users`

If you want the files/dirs created under `/home2/users` to be accessible by user1 (regardless who created it) in the future then you will need to set the SGID:
`chmod g+s /home2/users` 
Note that the above command can only be set by the `/home2/users` owner.

Can you elaborate more on your objective? Why does user1 needs to access user2's home directory? Will it be bad if user2 can access user1's home directory?

Comment: Man, this is the *fourth* duplicate of the same answer, and faulty in the exact same way! Please see my comments to the other answers for an idea of what I mean.